# Quickly split a dataframe by year in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel that looks like this

```
country <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
industry<- c("X","Y","Z","X","Y","Z","X","Y","Z")
x2006<- sample(1000:100000,9)
x2007<- sample(1000:100000,9)
x2008<- sample(1000:100000,9)
dat <- data.frame (country,industry,x2006,x2007,x2008)
```

I am doing something very simple like

```
dat2006 <- dat%>%
    select(country,industry,x2006)
```

then using `write.csv` to save it as its own file

What is the best way to do this if I wanted to repeat that and save a separate file for each year (i.e. column) in the data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sapply`:

```
sapply(grep("x", names(dat)), function(y)
       write.csv(dat[, c(1, 2, y)], 
                 paste0(names(dat[y]), ".csv"),
                 row.names = FALSE)
)
```

`grep` finds the columns with `x`, `sapply` loops through them. This will name your csv file the column name selected and save it in the working directory.

Note, you could specify the columns in other ways too. A few alternatives:

```
# using column locations (numbers) directly
sapply(3:5, function(y)
  write.csv(dat[, c(1, 2, y)], 
            paste0(names(dat[y]), ".csv"),
            row.names = FALSE)
)

# using column names
sapply(c("x2006", "x2007", "x2008"), function(y)
       write.csv(dat[, c("country", "industry", y)], 
                 paste0(names(dat[y]), ".csv"),
                 row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: This is really useful thanks, and thank you especially for including the different ways to specify the columns, not only useful but makes it even easier to understand! Can you please explain to me how to use the "function (y)" ?

Comment: The `function(y)` defines the function to iterate through the first part of the statement (ie, `grep(...)`, `3:5`, etc). You can think of `sapply` as a convenient way of writing a `for` loop, and instead of `for (y in ...)` you define a function. Hope that wasn't too confusing :)

Comment: haha I think that I get it! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x"), names_to = "year", values_to = "value") %>%
  split(.$year) %>%
  map(~ select(.x, country, industry, value)) %>%
  map2(names(.), ~ write_csv(.x, file = paste0("dat_", .y, ".csv")))
```

```
$x2006
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  country industry value
  <chr>   <chr>    <int>
1 A       X        99954
2 B       Y        27955
3 C       Z        36009
4 A       X         3061
5 B       Y        25612
6 C       Z        67307
7 A       X        96514
8 B       Y        97864
9 C       Z        43014

$x2007
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  country industry value
  <chr>   <chr>    <int>
1 A       X        83954
2 B       Y        96141
3 C       Z        62389
4 A       X        28568
5 B       Y        77503
6 C       Z        70458
7 A       X        34978
8 B       Y        35408
9 C       Z        68731

$x2008
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  country industry value
  <chr>   <chr>    <int>
1 A       X        29498
2 B       Y        62203
3 C       Z        98125
4 A       X        99549
5 B       Y        56839
6 C       Z        21621
7 A       X        84214
8 B       Y        85778
9 C       Z        90275
```